# ASP.NET Generate OnServerClick with dynamic control

Tags: asp.net

I am generating a "HtmlAnchor" control like this :

```
<li>
    <a id=\"AnchorButton\" onserverclick=\"HtmlAnchor_Click\" runat=\"server\">&lt;&lt;</a>
</li>
```

And i link the even to the control in the Page_Load :

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor AnchorButton = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor();
AnchorButton.Visible = false;
AnchorButton.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(this.HtmlAnchor_Click);
```

I have also defined the "HtmlAnchor_Click" method.
When I click on the HtmlAnchor control, the event is not firing.

How can I trigger this event ?

Comment: Hi sir stan, is this anchor button is declared on your ascx?

Comment: It is declared dynamically in my aspx.cs page.

Comment: Does that mean you're .cs creates a control without the page knowing where the control / html will be displayed isn't it? Or are you adding the control to some panel like pan.Controls.Add(HmtlAnchor);?

Comment: I am adding the control to a div id "pagination" like this :

pagination.InnerHtml = <span class=\"label\"><li><a id=\"AnchorButton\" onserverclick=\"HtmlAnchor_Click\" runat=\"server\">&lt;&lt;</a></li>";

Comment: well, the obvious fact here is that, InnerHtml is a literal, therefore you're hard-codedly writing the onserverclick as onserverclick, while if you try to do this in aspx and check in the literal html page, you'll see that onserver click becomes a javascript___doPostBack, so what you're doing is actually wrong. You should've placed the LI as a control and if your current page  = 1, then hide the "back" button, I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

***<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false"***

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a id="AnchorButton" onserverclick="Button1_Click" runat="server">&lt;&lt;</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
```

Codebehind:

```
void MyMethod()
{
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor AnchorButton = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor();
    AnchorButton.Visible = false;
    AnchorButton.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(this.Button1_Click);  
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("CLICK");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a panel control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel) in your aspx page and then dynamically add controls to the panel from server side.

For example:

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor AnchorButton = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlAnchor();
AnchorButton.Visible = false;
AnchorButton.ServerClick += new System.EventHandler(HtmlAnchor_Click);
panel.Controls.Add(AnchorButton);
```